# To check proposition of Self-referential sentence

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I want to prove two self-referential sentences $S, S_1$ are proposition or not. My approaches are given below.

Suppose, There is a statement :-

**$S :$ This statement '$S$' is false**

Now, There are 2 possible cases :-

**Case 1)-**  '$S$' is true

If statement '$S$' is true, It means statement   "This statement '$S$'  is false " is True which means Statement  '$S$'  is False  which is contradicting our assumption that  '$S$' is true. So, It is not a possible case which means statement '$S$' can't be true.

**Case 2):-**  '$S$' is false

If statement '$S$' is false, It means statement "This statement '$S$' is false " is False which means Statement '$S$' is True which is again contradicting our assumption that '$S$' is false. So, It is also not a possible case which means statement '$S$' can't be false.

Now, Proposition is a declarative statement which is either true or false but not both. Here, statement "This statement  '$S$'  is false"  is not getting any truth value either true or false. So, It is not a proposition.It is a paradox.

Now,   Suppose, There is a statement :-

**$S_1$ : This statement '$S_1$' is true**

Again, there are 2 possible cases :-

**Case 1):-** '$S_1$' is true

If statement '$S_1$' is true, It means statement "This statement '$S_1$' is true" is True which means Statement '$S_1$' is True which is not contradicting our assumption that '$S_1$' is true. So, It is a possible case.

**Case 2):-** '$S_1$' is false

If statement '$S_1$' is false, It means statement "This statement '$S_1$' is true" is False which means Statement '$S_1$' is False which is again not contradicting our assumption that '$S_1$' is false. So, It is also a possible case.

In both cases, statement  "This statement '$S_1$' is true"  is getting both truth values i.e. true and false. So, according to the definition of proposition,  "This statement '$S_1$' is true" is not a proposition and it is also not a paradox because we are not getting contradiction in both cases here.

I have tried for two cases  of  both self-referential  sentences $S$ and $S_1$ to prove both sentences are proposition or not.
I don't know my approach is right or not. I haven't found any valid stuff in internet.

Comment: "It is not a proposition.It is a paradox." Yes, **S** : The statement 'S' is false is the [Liar Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/)

Comment: For **S1**, it is not a paradox but a "good" statement: the statement "X is true" has the same truth-value of X.

Comment: @Mauro you check my conclusion for both sentences are right or not. If not please correct this.

Comment: @Mauro many websitesaying  $S_1$ is proposition. I am confuse, please help.

Comment: What's the difference between your $S$ and $S_1$? Can you give reference to the "many website* you mentioned?

Comment: @mohottnad [See this site example 17](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/propositional-logic-propositions-examples/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like in most cases you're stating both your sentence **$S$** (liar) and your sentence **$S_1$** with quotation mark to *mention* itself via the same English language without object/meta language differentiation, since most natural languages are closed the [liar case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) is like Russell's paradox its truth value is *overdetermined* thus cannot be determined *logically*, therefore it's paradoxical and cannot be a proposition. As noted in the wiki reference, there're many different solutions out of this paradox.

Your sentence **$S_1$** apparently lacks grounding evidence to judge its truth condition (it may be either true or false as you rightly analyzed) thus its truth value cannot be determined *empirically* but without any logical paradox, therefore it's a proposition though its truth value is not known yet. This is not uncommon like $P=NP$ which is a well formed proposition attracting many people to try to determine its truth value though currently no one knows for sure yet. So in this natural language common case, your referenced website saying your second sentence is a true proposition is not totally right, but we can say for sure that it's a proposition unparadoxically.

Comment: could you explain difference between paradox and liar paradox?

Comment: @User4567 Paradox is a major topic originated from philosophy and Quine classified it into 3 major categories as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox#Quine's_classification). Liar and Russell paradoxes belong to his 3rd category-antimony, which means we only need logic and semantic meaning of a language to arrive at contradiction in an armchair without any other empirical knowledge. Another famous Zeno's paradox belongs to falsidical category and needs empirical knowledge of physics. Hope this helps...